# consteval broken? on Apple clang++

Tags: c++, c++20, apple-clang

What doe the diagnostic below mean? I do not understand how a call to a correct consteval function with no arguments can possibly be anything other than a constant expression.

```
#include <iostream>
template<int x>
struct X {
consteval static int get() { return x; }
int f() const { return get(); }
};

int main() {
  ::std::cout << X<4>().get() << ::std::endl;
}
```

```
~/felix>clang++ -std=c++20 -ferror-limit=1 xx.cxx
xx.cxx:4:17: error: call to consteval function 'X::get' is not a constant expression
int f() const { return get(); }
                        ^
```

clang is confused. Here's the proof: this works:

```
int f() const { int a[get()]; return sizeof(a); }
```

clang thinks a consteval function can ONLY be used in a context where a constant expression is required: whether or not that is the rule in the Standard it's nonsense. In my actual code, the function is successfully called without a diagnostic if qualified by a template typename parameter, and is used in a context which does not require a constant.

Comment: "_Here's the proof: this works:_": By default Clang allows variable-length arrays. So the test doesn't show what you want to show. Try it again with `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in (upstream) Clang 15. Don't know which Apple Clang version that translates to. See https://godbolt.org/z/qaTj7Przf.

Comment: @-user17732522~/felix>clang++ -std=c++20 -ferror-limit=1 -pedantic-errors xx.cxx
~/felix>./a.out
4

Comment: @-user17732522 ~/felix>clang++ --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0

Comment: @-user17732522 ok, thanks! .. Apple clang is usually quite a bit behind and at least the library is modified as well. Spaceship <=> doesn't work correctly either in my version (which was updated today lol)

Comment: Ah ok. You are right that it works even with `-pedantic-errors`. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode most recent versions of Xcode are using upstream LLVM/Clang 14. So you'll have to wait at least another release to get the bugfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is well-formed and this is a clang bug which has been [fixed](https://godbolt.org/z/Y1zq3deGd) in clang 15.0.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y1zq3deGd)

Comment: Thanks! Whew! I really need that to be a compile time constant, since in the real code it's using polymorphic recursion over parameter packs, and it has to be not only fast at run time, I'm about to use it in a context where it does have to be a constant expression.